# TSQL Insert the column default value from Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'd like to use the column's default value in an stored procedure insert, so that I don't have to repeat the default value in multiple places (it could change... DRY principle).

The T-SQL INSERT operation has a handy 'default' keyword that I can use as follows:

```
Declare @newA varchar(10)
Set @newA = 'Foo2'

-- I can use "default" like so...
Insert into Table_1 (
    A, 
    B) 
Values (
    @newA, 
    default)
```

However, If I need to do something conditional,  I can't seem to get the case statement to return 'default'.

```
-- How do I use 'default' in a case statement? 
INSERT INTO Table_1 (
    A,
    B )
VALUES (
    @newA,
    CASE WHEN (@newA <> 'Foo2') THEN 'bar' ELSE default END)
-- > yeilds "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'."
```

I *could* insert the default, and then update as needed like so:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (
    A,
    B )
VALUES (
    @newA,
    default)
UPDATE Table_1 
SET B = CASE WHEN (A <> 'Foo2') THEN 'bar' ELSE B END
WHERE ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

But I'd really like somebody to tell me "There's a better way..."

Here's a table definition for this example if it helps...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1 (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    A varchar(10) NULL,
    B varchar(10) NULL  )  
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Table_1_A DEFAULT 'A-Def' FOR A
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Table_1_B DEFAULT 'B-Def' FOR B
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default` only works from within a `VALUES()` block, which does not seem to be an acceptable value in a `CASE` statement; you could use an if statement to determine what to insert:

```
DECLARE @newA varchar(10) = 'Foo2'

IF (@newA <> 'Foo2')
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Table_1 (A, B)
   SELECT @newA, 'bar'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   --If you are using default values, you do not have to specify the column
   INSERT INTO Table_1 (A) 
   SELECT @newA
END
```

I think this is better than updating after an insert, so that you only insert correct data into your table.  It also keeps the number of INSERTS/UPDATES to 1.  You should also be careful when you using @@IDENTITY due to scoping.  Consider looking into [**SCOPE_IDENTITY()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

Comment: So basically I have to split it out in advance... at least there is only one insert/update and I don't have to repeat myself on the the default value...

Comment: I am disappointed with the SQL team that the result_expression of a CASE statement can't specify the equivalent of 'default'!  or maybe it's the insert statement that doesn't play nice with the syntax.

Comment: @DanO It appears to be a limitation of DEFAULT only being acceptable inside VALUES() per the [**INSERT documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)